# C# TDD, Integration Test Repository, Verify Add Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm relatively new to TDD and I have a project with repository pattern with EF in the repository class. 
Now I want to test these repositories and I have already mocked the DbContext successfully. (Using Moq and nunit)

Now I want to validate adding a object to my mocked database. The test says, test passed, but I'm quite sure, my test is not correct because I queried the database before the Add method, returns 5 objects, then I call the Add method and query the database again, still only 5 objects, but I would expect now 6 objects. Am I missing here something?

Model Address.cs

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Person {get; set; }
    //some more properties
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public async Task<AdresseDto> AddAdresseAsync(AdresseDto adresseDto)
{
   try
   {
       ctx.Adresse.Add(adresse);
       await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
       adresseDto.Id = adresse.Id;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("ohoh");
       Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine("ohoh");
       return null;
   }

return adresseDto;
```

}

UnitTest.cs

```
public async Task Test_AddTestAddress_ReturnsAddressWithId()
{
     var dummyDataInDb = AddressHelper.GetAdressen(5);
     var dummyData4Db = AddressHelper.GetAdressen(1).FirstOrDefault();
//AddressHelper returns just some dummy objects

     InitializeMock<Adresse>.With(dummyDataInDb.AsQueryable(), out AdresseMock);
     XaDbMock = new Mock<xaModel>();
     XaDbMock
         .Setup(x => x.Adresse)
         .Returns(AdresseMock.Object);
     _repository = NewAddressRepository(XaDbMock.Object);

     //When
     var addressesInDb = await _repository.GetAllAdressenAsync();
     var result = await _repository.AddAdresseAsync(dummyData4Db);
     var addressesInDbAfter = await _repository.GetAllAdressenAsync();

     //Then
     Assert.IsNotNull(addressesInDb);
     Assert.AreEqual(5, addressesInDb.Count);
     Assert.IsNotNull(result);
     Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Id);
     Assert.IsNotNull(addressesInDbAfter);
     Assert.AreEqual(6, addressesInDbAfter.Count);
 }
```

InitializeMock.cs

```
public class InitializeMock<T> where T : class 
{
    public static void With(IQueryable<T> dummyData, out Mock<DbSet<T>> mock)
    {
        mock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        //Required for async tasks
        mock.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(dummyData.GetEnumerator()));
        //Required for async tasks
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(x => x.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(dummyData.Provider));

        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(x => x.Expression)
            .Returns(dummyData.Expression);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
            .Returns(dummyData.ElementType);
        mock.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
            .Returns(dummyData.GetEnumerator);
    }
}
```

If something is missing, please let me know. I'll provide any neccessary informations you need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you debug your unit test, do you hit the `catch()` block of your `add` method? Personally i've only done it two ways: 1. MS Fakes (the best way) 2. LocalDb or In Memory Db (e.g. `Effort). The downside to (1) is that you need Enterprise VS for it.

Comment: No, I don't hit the catch block. That's the part where I'm wondering what really happens in the background. No exception but however the counter in my mock database does not increment. Maybe I don't understand mocking the way I should? Could you please tell me more about ms fakes? I've never heard of it. And could you give me a link or hint about in memory db? I thought this would meant some kind of mocking. Thank you

Comment: Fakes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx
In memory db: https://tflamichblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/introducing-effort/